# Regex and java to ignore keywords and string inside quotation

Tags: java, regex

I'm searching for keywords that has to start with a letter followed by a letter or a character or nothing

Things I am looking for: x, x2, xx, and so on

the regular expression i have is [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]

I need to ignore words such as INT, WRITE, READ and so on, not sure how to implement

also if it comes across a string with quotation, I need it to ignore whatever that is inside the quotation?

any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You realize `x` is in between `a-z` right?

Comment: I figured it was a bit misleading so i edited it. Yes X1 X are one of the key words I am looking for.

Comment: I'm glad you cleared that up :) I was getting scared for a minute.

Comment: No problem lol, I was like what? Then I read what I wrote and was like ohhh that's why haha

Comment: How about some examples of "comes across a string with quotation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear to me.  If you want to accept words that start with a letter, and continue with either a letter or a digit (or an underscore) ; but exclude words from a list, you can use the regex:

```
(?!\b(?:INT|WRITE|READ)\b)\b[A-Za-z]\w*\b
```

If, instead of a list, you want to exclude words that consist of all capitalized letters, then try:

```
(?!(?:\b[A-Z]+\b))\b[A-Za-z]\w*\b
```

In Java, I believe you need to double the backslashes for the metacharacters, so it might be something like:

```
"(?!\\b(?:INT|WRITE|READ)\\b)\\b[A-Za-z]\\w*\\b"
```

If you also want to exclude strings within quotes, you could use something like:

```
"[^"]+"|((?!\b(?:INT|WRITE|READ)\b)\b[A-Za-z]\w*\b)
```

and then check to see if there is anything within capturing group 1 which would NOT include the phrases delineated by the double quote marks.

Another option would be to replace all those parameters you don't want with nothing -- the word list as well as the quoted text.  In Java, something like:

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("\"[^\"]*\"|\\b(?:WRITE|INT|READ)\\b", "");
```

Comment: Yes you're right. The first answer is what I'm looking for, but it doesn't work. I get an error when I put it in my program for some reason

Comment: What did you try in your program?  And what is the error you get?

Comment: Did what you did about the back slash and it worked perfectly appreciate it. can you explain to me what's going with what you wrote?

Comment: First you do the negative lookahead to ensure you cannot match the words in the list; if that succeeds, you match the next sequence of characters that matches your pattern -- letter followed by one or more other characters.   By the way, if my response satisfied your requirements, please mark it as the answer

Comment: If I had something like this: x2xsd " ignr" and wanted to ignore what's inside the quote, not sure how to do that

Comment: the negation i wrote is this but it's not working for some reason: (?!\\b(?:\"(\\s)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\\s)?\")

Comment: @JosephMaanAnayee Use the last suggestion in my answer, and look only at capturing group 1.

Comment: can you elaborate more a little bit please? I am new to regex and still learning, have been watching youtube videos about it.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/  is a good site to use to start to learn about this.